# Insert 15 min datetime in hourly intervals

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with 3 columns of which the first column is a datetime.

It looks like this

```
Datetime            Level1   Level2
2016-02-24 01:00    12       15
2016-02-24 02:00    14       13
2016-02-24 03:00    8        12
```

Now I would like to add 15 min interval values between the hourly values. However, Level1 and Level2 gets the same values as its previous hour. It should look like this:

```
Datetime            Level1   Level2
2016-02-24 01:00    12       15
2016-02-24 01:15    12       15
2016-02-24 01:30    12       15
2016-02-24 01:45    12       15
2016-02-24 02:00    14       13
2016-02-24 02:15    14       13
2016-02-24 02:30    14       13
2016-02-24 02:45    14       13
2016-02-24 03:00    8        12
2016-02-24 03:15    8        12
2016-02-24 03:30    8        12
2016-02-24 03:45    8        12
```

I can't think of a way how to do this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create copies of the original data frame where you increment the `Datetime` column by 15 minutes each and then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) followed by [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) to get the final result:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['2016-02-24 01:00', 12, 15],
          ['2016-02-24 02:00', 14, 13],
          ['2016-02-24 03:00',  8, 12]],
    columns=['Datetime', 'Level1', 'Level2']
)
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

intervals = [df]
while len(intervals) < 4:
    new = intervals[-1].copy()
    new['Datetime'] += timedelta(minutes=15)
    intervals.append(new)

result = pd.concat(intervals).sort_values(by='Datetime')
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the datetime as index (after converting to datetime), and use the asfreq method, with a forward fill, to fill the null values with previous values :

```
#thanks to @a_guest for the cleaned sample data

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['2016-02-24 01:00', 12, 15],
          ['2016-02-24 02:00', 14, 13],
          ['2016-02-24 03:00',  8, 12]],
    columns=['Datetime', 'Level1', 'Level2']
)
df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])

df = df.set_index('Datetime')

df.asfreq('15min',method='pad')

                 Level1 Level2
Datetime        
2016-02-24 01:00:00 12  15
2016-02-24 01:15:00 12  15
2016-02-24 01:30:00 12  15
2016-02-24 01:45:00 12  15
2016-02-24 02:00:00 14  13
2016-02-24 02:15:00 14  13
2016-02-24 02:30:00 14  13
2016-02-24 02:45:00 14  13
2016-02-24 03:00:00 8   12
```

**NB** : your question says 15 minutes intervals between the times, and your latest time is 3pm, not 4pm, as shared in your data.

Comment: If we wanted to see the quarters of 03:00, what should we do in this situation? So what would we do if we wanted the time interval to end at 03:45?